# How to  format a homework question?

Tags: discussion, homework

I'd like to propose an addition to the questions [How to ask a homework question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) based on the following observation. Most questions that are in fact homework questions are copied verbatim from the original text. Shouldn't it be standard procedure in almost any medium to -quote- the copy?

For example, some questions go like this:

**For any $x$, show that $f(x) = g(x)$.**

The natural disgruntlement that is often commented on ("Why are you telling us to do this? Did you have a question?") could be avoided if the question were treated as a copy and quoted:

> For any $x$, show that $f(x) = g(x)$.

That would sidestep all sorts of common misunderstandings and complaints.

The major difficulty I see with this is that those who write questions like this don't care about formatting it for the community standards anyway. But I thought the connection with copying and plagiarism would be more convincing to newcomers/homework leeches to teach them to quote would be more successful than trying to teach them to use the homework tag.

Comment: In point of fact, I tend to do precisely this when I edit a question which has the text of the problem and some other discussion. Nonetheless, *simply* posting the copy still produces the problem of producing a post with nothing but an order, even if it is clearly "a copy and quote".

Comment: I left the **answer** template posted to that other question as a CW for a reason `:)`. Please consider adding this to [that answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question/1804#1804) with an appropriate topic heading! Note that I however agrees with what Arturo wrote: quoting the exact homework question should be done *in addition to*, not in place of the other guidelines.

Comment: @Arturo, @Willie: Oh yeah, I'm in total agreement; this is in addition, I don't want other things replaced. I think quoting is necessary (like giving references) but not sufficient. Argh...thinking makes this more complicated...they should also **obviously** give the text reference they are copying from. But maybe that is a disincentive for the poster to do the minimum we're asking here.

Comment: @Willie: I don't see an actual 'template' (that looks like a homework question to fill in at that page. Is it in that page or is there a link to a stackexchange 'question' that is the template?

Comment: I don't think I was using template in the way you meant `:)` What I meant to say is that I started a template for the FAQ entry which we should fill in with more information, like your contribution above. I should hope we don't need to provide Mad-Lib style templates for question askers in general!