# List of Generalisations of Common Questions

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, big-list

Here is a list of generalised [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)s to which other questions may be deduped against, split by topic (please edit the question).

---

## [Arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+arithmetic) [arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

- Laws of signs (minus times minus is plus): [Why is negative times negative = positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9933)
- Order of operations in arithmetic: [What is the standard interpretation of order of operations for the basic arithmetic operations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36270)

---

## [Algebra/Precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+algebra-precalculus) [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus)

- Solving equations with multiple absolute values: [What is the best way to solve an equation involving multiple absolute values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3153)
- Extraneous solutions to equations with a square root: [Is there a name for this strange solution to a quadratic equation involving a square root?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61252)
- Principal $n$-th roots:

  - [Significance of $\sqrt[n]{a^n} $?!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13094)
  - [Why is the even root of a number always positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41878)
  - Also see “Exponentiation” below
- $0! = 1$: [Prove $0! = 1$ from first principles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969)
- Partial fraction decomposition of rational functions: [Converting multiplying fractions to sum of fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83175/)
- Highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $N!$, number of zeros at the end of $N!$ and related questions:
  [Highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $N!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/)

#### [Exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+exponentiation) [exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation)

- Solving $x^x=y$ for $x$: [Is $x^x=y$ solvable for $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54210)
- What is the value of $0^0$? [Zero to the zero power – is $0^0=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/zero-to-the-zero-power-is-00-1)
- [Why $\sqrt{-1 \times -1} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169)
- [Why $(-2)^{2.5}$ isn't equal to $((-2)^{25})^{1/10}?\,$ [Fractional powers of negative numbers]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025)

---

## [Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+calculus) [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus)

- Indefinite integrals obtained using different techniques appear different (but are actually the same up to a constant): [Getting different answers when integrating using different techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques)
- Integrating polynomial and rational expressions of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$: [Evaluating $\int P(\sin x, \cos x) \text{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29980)
- Integration using partial fractions: [Integration by partial fractions; how and why does it work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20963)
- Intuitive meaning of Euler's constant $e$: [Intuitive Understanding of the constant "$e$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/intuitive-understanding-of-the-constant-e)
- Evaluating limits of the form $\lim_{x\to \infty} P(x)^{1/n}-x$ where $P(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ is a monic polynomial:  [Limits: How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{0}}-x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30040)
- Finding the limit of rational functions at infinity: [Finding the limit of $\frac{Q(n)}{P(n)}$ where $Q,P$ are polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33970)
- $\zeta(2)$: [Different ways to prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (the Basel problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337)
- Divergence of the harmonic series: [Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ not converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/)
- Universal Chord Theorem: [Universal Chord Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16374)
- Nested radical series: [Limit of the nested radical $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501)
- Derivative of a function expressed as $f(x)^{g(x)}$: [Differentiation of $x^{\sqrt{x}}$, how?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262280/differentiation-of-x-sqrtx-how/)
- [Limit of the sequence $\{n^n/n!\}$, is this sequence bounded, convergent and eventually monotonic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535226/limit-of-the-sequence-nn-n?rq=1) ; [What's the limit of the sequence $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/whats-the-limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-fracnnn?lq=1)
- [Single Variable Calculus Reference Recommendations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/901622/9754)
- Removable discontinuity: [How can a function with a hole (removable discontinuity) equal a function with no hole?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164182/how-can-a-function-with-a-hole-removable-discontinuity-equal-a-function-with-n)
- [If $f$ is continuous, nonnegative on $[a, b]$, show that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d(x) = 0$ iff $f(x) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224799/if-f-is-continuous-nonnegative-on-a-b-show-that-int-ab-fx-dx)

#### Calculus Meets Geometry

- Volume of intersection between cylinders

  - [Two cylinders, same radius, orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494249). This post is not particularly good but there are many existing duplicate-links. Note that this can be done [without calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237908).
  - Two cylinders variation: [different radii](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167660) (orthogonal), [non-orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338708) (same radius), and [elliptic cylinders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799049) (essentially unsolved).
  - Three cylinders: [same radius and orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923508).

---

## [Combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+combinatorics) [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics)

- Stars and bars, making change: [Counting bounded integer solutions to $\sum_ia_ix_i\leqq n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/910809)
- Dice: [How many ways can the sum of $n$ dice be $s$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970523/how-many-ways-can-the-sum-of-n-dice-be-s/)
- Stars and bars with variable upper limits: [Extended stars-and-bars problem(where the upper limit of the variable is bounded)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded)
- Password counting:
  [How many ways can you create a password of 10 characters long that has at least one lowercase letter (a-z) and at least one number ($0-9$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/260446/357390)
- Derangements: [Number of permutations of $n$ elements where no number $i$ is in position $i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14666)
- Bell numbers, equivalence relations: [How many equivalence relations on a set with 4 elements.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/676519)
- [How many ways can N elements be partitioned into subsets of size K?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/640558)
- [Seating arrangements of four men and three women around a circular table](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1305844)
- [How many different spanning trees of $K_n \setminus e$ are there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/666997/) (or [Spanning Trees of the Complete Graph minus an edge](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/575163/))

---

## [Functional equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+functional-equations) [functional-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-equations)

- [Is there a name for function with the exponential property $f(x+y)=f(x) \cdot f(y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22069)

---

## [Geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+geometry) [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)

- The "World's Hardest Elementary Geometry Problem": [Langley's Adventitious Angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942)

---

## [Graph theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+graph-theory) [graph-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory)

[How to tell whether two graphs are isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486944/how-to-tell-whether-two-graphs-are-isomorphic)

---

## [Group theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+group-theory) [group-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory)

[For a finite group of order $2n$ does there exist $x$ such that $x\ast x=e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726138/for-a-finite-group-of-order-2n-does-there-exist-x-such-that-x-ast-x-e/726150#726150)

[An element of a group has the same order as its inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008610/an-element-of-a-group-has-the-same-order-as-its-inverse/1008610#1008610)

[How to prove $\,{\rm order}(a^k) = n/\gcd(n,k)\,$ for $\,n={\rm order}(a)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906718/how-to-prove-ak-n-gcdn-k-whenever-a-n)

---

## [Linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+linear-algebra) [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra)

- Definition of Matrix Multiplication: (Maybe there should just be one canonical one?)

  - [Intuition behind Matrix Multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31725)
  - [What does matrix multiplication have to do with scalar multiplication?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29792)
- On the determinant:

  - [What's an intuitive way to think about the determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668)
- Determinants of special matrices:

  - [Determinant of a rank $1$ update of a scalar matrix, or characteristic polynomial of a rank $1$ matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904926)
  - [How to compute the determinant of a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266998)
- Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues

  - [How Do I Compute the Eigenvalues of a Small Matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583883/how-do-i-compute-the-eigenvalues-of-a-small-matrix)
- Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization

  - [The Need for the Gram-Schmidt Process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961727/the-need-for-the-gram-schmidt-process)
- [Prove that A + I is invertible if A is nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/140348)

  - A generalization [for non-commutative rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119904)
- [Interpreting the row echelon form of an (augmented) matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856127/how-to-interpret-row-echelon-form/4856128#4856128)

---

## [Logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+logic) [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic)

- [What is the difference between $\forall x\exists y$ and $\exists y\forall x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64500/confused-between-nested-quantifiers)

---

## [Number Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+elementary-number-theory) [elementary-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory)[number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)

- [Modular exponentiation by hand ($a^b\bmod c$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228)
- Universal divisibility rules: [Trick to find multiples mentally](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/89623)
- Solving the congruence $x^2\equiv1\pmod n$: [Number of solutions of $x^2=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/104961)
- [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1)
- [Can $\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{m}$ be rational if neither $n,m$ are perfect squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457382/can-sqrtn-sqrtm-be-rational-if-neither-n-m-are-perfect-squares)
- [What is the period of the decimal expansion of $\frac mn$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140583/compute-the-period-of-a-decimal-number-a-priori)
- [When does $p^2$ divide $an^k + bp$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464749/when-does-p2-divide-ank-bp)
- [Posts related to proving that among any $2n - 1$ integers, there's always a subset of $n$ which sum to a multiple of $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3754764/602049)
- Formula for Hensel's lemma: [Hensel lifting square roots $\!\bmod p\,$ to $\!\bmod p^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165176/357390)

---

## [Sequences/Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+sequences-and-series) [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) (also [summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+summation) [summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation))

- Geometric Series: [Values of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^N x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023)
- Summing series of the form $\sum_n (n+1) x^n$: [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732)
- Finding the limit of rational functions at infinity: [Finding the limit of $\frac{Q(n)}{P(n)}$ where $Q,P$ are polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33970)
- $\zeta(2)$: [Different ways to prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (the Basel problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337)
- Divergence of the harmonic series: [Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ not converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255)
- [Limit of the nested radical $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501)
- Limit of exponential sequence and $n$ factorial: [Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$, $x \in \Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550)
- [To sum $1+2+3+\cdots$ to $-\frac1{12}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-1-over-12)
- Recursively defined sequences: [Limit of a mean sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921376/limit-of-a-mean-sequence)

---

## [Elementary set theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+elementary-set-theory) [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory)

- The set of all [finite subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200389/show-that-the-set-of-all-finite-subsets-of-mathbbn-is-countable?lq=1)  / [$n$-element subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714998/prove-that-n-is-countable-for-every-n) / [2-element subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386808/show-that-the-set-of-all-2-element-subsets-of-mathbbn-is-countable?lq=1) of $\Bbb N$ is countable
- There are different sizes of infinity: [What Does it Really Mean to Have Different Kinds of Infinities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1/different-kinds-of-infinities)

---

## [Trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+trigonometry) [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry)

- Solving triangles: [Solving Triangles (finding missing sides/angles given 3 sides/angles)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106539)
- (Confusing) notation for inverse functions ($\sin^{-1}$ vs. $\arcsin$): [$\arcsin$ written as $\sin^{-1}(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30317)
- Notation for the square of a trigonometric function (What does $\sin(x)^2$ or $\sin^2$ mean?): [What are the meanings of $\operatorname{trig}(x)^n$ and $\operatorname{trig}^n(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1172760/)

## [Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+polynomials) [polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials)

- [How to prove $\,x^a-1 \mid x^b-1 \iff a\mid b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609900/how-to-prove-xa-1-mid-xb-1-iff-a-mid-b)
- [Is there a systematic way of solving cubic equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61725/167197)

Comment: Regarding the tags question, what do others think of the "abstract duplicate" tag?

Comment: Are we also attempting to make these questions community wikis? This was the case with the first one for calculus (integrals of polynomials in sines and cosines), but doesn't seem to have been done for the second one yet.

Comment: @Arturo: I had flagged that to make it CW. Since I expect we will just be consolidating different answers (perhaps from different people), making it CW would be the right thing to do...

Comment: @eric I would support a simpler [faq] tag which is what these are, correct? frequently asked *math* questions on this site?

Comment: @Jeff: I actually almost edited that tag in! But was afraid faq might be a moderator only tag and it might be inappropriate. I think we should tag it that way, to make it easier to search etc. In fact, I will go ahead and do it.

Comment: @Isaac: The geometric series one needs one to know what a limit is, so algebra-precalculus might not be exactly right. But I do agree the partial sums one falls in there, so it might be better to include it there, making it easier to look for it, when people actually start closing as dupes.

Comment: @Moron: Infinite geometric series are very often a precalculus topic; limits are fairly common, too; though now I'm wondering how infinite series can be more common than limits... perhaps because limits as $n\to\infty$ are often done with rational functions and graph end behavior without needing to talk rigorously (or even conceptually) about limits in general.

Comment: @Isaac: Yeah, I guess a lot of stuff is left for 'later'.

Comment: Shouldn't the questions be "answers" rather than edits to the question?

Comment: @Arturo: Yes, we could have one answer per category. Having one question per answer might not be that good. The intent was to keep the list in one place so that we can browse through easily.

Comment: @Moron: Yes, I understand; but (i) we probably don't want this question to keep popping up as "unanswered". And (ii) I think if we had one answer per category (or per tag) and have people "add it to the list" there it would make more sense. Right now the question is fine, but if this keeps up, the question itself will grow too lengthy to be manageable, I think.

Comment: @Arturo: I think having this question pop up periodically is probably a good thing :-) I do agree with one tag answer thing. If enough people upvote your comment, I will make the edits :-)

Comment: @Arturo: I think that questions from the unanswered list only get bumped if they have an answer (necessarily none accepted or with positive vote count).  (If I'm wrong, will someone please inform me?)  But I agree with (ii).

Comment: @Moron, @Arturo : I agree with only adding a Question to one spot on this list. For example, the limit question is tagged as both "calculus" and "limits," but is only put in one category on this page.  On the other hand, I much prefer the idea of editing this question rather than posting answers to it. I think it keeps things concise, and much more organized, even if the question itself does eventually become quite long.  (The conciseness is a big thing.  If we have too many categories, the answers could stretch onto multiple pages which I feel is worse)

Comment: @Eric: It'll be much harder to find questions, especially when the list gets long, if they aren't listed under all relevant categories.

Comment: @Isaac:  But that might lengthen the list by a large amount.  I mean both the questions in the calculus tag have other tags, namely "Integral" and "Limit," but I don't think it is a good idea to create separate categories and put them in those categories.  That wouldn't be a useful addition.  The geometric series is definitely in the series category, why does it need to be in algebra/pre-calculus as well?  Tagging the question as such is of course a good idea.  Then searching the FAQ tag on the main site is very easy.  But in this list? I don't understand the need.

Comment: Question:  Should questions such as "Why is $0.999..=1?$"  "Why is $0^0=1$? and "Why does $0!=1$" be added to this list?  Should we make one question dealing with all of them at once?  I mean they are asked frequently enough, occasionally with slight variations, but are definitely _not_ "abstract generalizations."  Thoughts?  How could one question be added that deals with all of these type of things at once?

Comment: @Eric: I guess it is a judgement call.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I think it'd be better for each tagged subject to have a corresponding meta thread of faqs, abstract duplicates, etc. These could be displayed to low-rep users when they add a tag to a question. Better we could force them to choose a subject/tag *before* composing a question, so they see the subject-specific faqs first. This would go a long way towards removing the noise/overhead generated by duplicate questions (a big problem for a general-level math forum since exercises are often tweaked year-after-year to eliminate copying - yielding abstract, not exact, duplicates).

Comment: @Arturo: I am waiting for 2 more upvotes to your comment :-)

Comment: @Willie: Please tag the questions you add here with the (faq) tag too.

Comment: @Moron: thanks for the reminder. It has been done. I do hope there exists a better candidate for that category though.

Comment: I don't understand why geometric series are under two categories.

Comment: @bill the automatically generated faqs (based on internal link count) for the tag are fairly close to what you're describing.. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus?sort=faq perhaps the tag wiki page itself would get us the rest of the way there? http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/calculus/info

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, I know about the automagically generated faqs. Of course one could do *much* better if one had explicit manual control. AI is far from up to the task, esp. in deeply abstract domains such as mathematics.

Comment: @all :  Two questions:  $$(1)$$  Should all of the posts be flagged for moderator attention and made community wiki?  $$(2)$$ When making an abstract duplicate page, should we create a new separate question, or modify an existing question?  (Or should we just use our judgment, and if there is a suitable host, take it over, and if not create a new question?)  From experience, there isn't always a suitable question to modify.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2 should be added, as questions about $\zeta(2)$ arise frequently.

Comment: @Asaf: I believe you have enough rep to make some edits :-) The more people that are involved, the better.

Comment: Maybe we should add [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215) to the list (at least until this silliness dies down and people move on to other things)?

Comment: May be [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67889/11619) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/16459/11619) should be brought under the common umbrella of obvious consequences of the binomial formula?

Comment: Is the goal to find examples "in the wild" of common questions, that we then coopt and retag as faq? Or do we create new community wiki questions tagged faq specifically for the purpose of answering them comprehensively (as was done on SO)?

Comment: Dear @yasmar, whenever you add a question to this list, you are expected to also add [tag:faq] to the question you have just linked to, as instructed at the very top. I have done it for you this time.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you, and sorry for missing that instruction.

Comment: The former. And we usually don't bother until at least a couple dupes appears.

Comment: Mostly the former, as Willie indicated, but sometimes the latter when there have been numerous specific examples of some nicer general principle, none of which would have been easy to edit into the canonical question.

Comment: Hmm, I actually think it's a good thing that this "question" has no upvoted answers (and to that effect, please don't upvote any!). The bot will bump it up periodically, and we always get a reminder of these dupes.

Comment: @J.M. Can I add: **[What is $\lim \frac{x^n}{n!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac2nn-0/130968#130968)** to the list?

Comment: @PeterT.off: If you think variants of it have been asked at least 2-3 times, sure, go ahead.

Comment: @Aryabhata Yes, I have seen it enough times.

Comment: @PeterT.off: Please don't forget to edit the question  1) to include the full general problem. 2) state that it is being repurposed (see other such questions from list above for a template which you can cut and paste) 3) and tag it as (faq).

Comment: @Peter: sure, and no need to ask for my permission; this is a CW post! Make sure to add the [tag:faq] tag to the question in main after adding it here.

Comment: @Aryabhata I got the last step. What are the first two?

Comment: @PeterT.off: You will be adding links to _questions_ here. Not answers. So the question should be stated in general terms so that it is applicable for inclusion here. See this for instance: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn and compare the current form with version 1.

Comment: @Aryabhata I see! I'll do that.

Comment: @Marvis: Please just don't add in questions like that. We first should generalize the question, add an answer to the generalized question (if missing), tag it with the faq tag. Future minor variants can now be closed as dupe of this. Also, there should only be one (generalized) question, rather than a bunch of related question. I am rolling back your edit for now. I suggest you look at some of the other questions in the list to see what I mean.

Comment: @Aryabhata Ok. Let me then generalize one of the two questions and provide more detailed answer and do as you say.

Comment: @Aryabhata I have generalized the question here. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/how-come-the-number-n-can-terminate-in-exactly-1-2-3-4-or-6-zeroes-but-n and updated the answer. I also marked the related questions to be closed down and flagged them for moderator's attention.

Comment: @Marvis: Seems reasonable.

Comment: @Marvis: Feel free to edit this list with that question :-)

Comment: @Aryabhata Yea sure I will add it. I just wanted to make sure the other questions get closed and linked to the generalized question.

Comment: Seems to be a curious bug: the last entry's link does not render as the name of the linked question. Very peculiar.

Comment: @MJD: Please add just one question on a single topic which can be used to _close_ the others. You don't add the others here (in this case you added multiple on pyramidal numbers). This is meant to be a list of generalized questions which answer a bunch of minor variations etc. Also, the question needs to be tagged as (faq).

Comment: I think this and the MathJax 'reference' should be blindingly obvious to anyone asking a question (and myself!).

Comment: Some common divisibility problems: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473) ([special case](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225289)) and also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413473)

Comment: I am honestly quite pissed that the answers here were upvoted, defeating the bumping mechanism. Oh well.

Comment: @J.M.; Same here. But then I have stopped caring :-)

Comment: [Finding eigenvectors of small matrices by solving the characteristic polynomial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583883/how-do-i-compute-the-eigenvalues-of-a-small-matrix)

Comment: [Explanation of how to compute eigenvectors by using determinants and solving the resultant polynomial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583883/how-do-i-compute-the-eigenvalues-of-a-small-matrix)

Comment: If this isn't already on here, we should probably include [Complex exponentiation “proof” that $\pi=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359927/complex-exponentiation-proof-that-pi-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [for which complex $a,b,c$ does $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ hold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347504/for-which-complex-a-b-c-does-abc-abc-hold?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [$1=e^{2\pi}$ where did I make my mistake?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980442/1-e2%cf%80-where-did-i-make-a-mistake?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Are you suggestion we develop our own `documentation` as on stackoverflow? We all know how that went...

Comment: @YuiTo: do you envision the new question you edited and put in here to be linked to by multiple other questions (as opposed to other, possibly previously posted questions in the same vein)?

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Sure. I think it has been asked in many different forms before and I couldn't find any post alike here.

Comment: I'm surprised there's nothing here on differential equations.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:  Note that "[generalize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generalize)" and "[generalise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/generalise)" are equally valid spellings.

Comment: This sort of product of limits question gets asked a bunch https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653309/why-do-i-get-two-different-answers-while-doing-this-simple-limit-math

Answer (score 28):

## Burnside lemma and Pólya enumeration theorem examples

Observe that  the convention at the  OEIS is that  the term *necklace*
refers to  the slots  being arranged around  a circle  with rotational
symmetry  acting  on them.  Similarly  the  term *bracelet*  indicates
reflections acting on the slots  in addition to rotations. This is the
difference  between the  cyclic  group $C_n$  acting  on $n$  elements
(necklace) and the dihedral group $D_n$ on $n$ elements (bracelet).

**symmetries of polyhedra**

- [Coloring the faces of a hypercube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/coloring-the-faces-of-a-hypercube/)
- [Burnside's formula on a hexagon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485081/burnsides-formula-on-a-hexagon)
- [Coloring the faces of a regular dodecahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380807/)
- [Coloring the edges of a regular dodecahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628360/)
- [Edge colorings of the cube and Power Group Enumeration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150016/edge-coloring-of-the-cube)
- [Put two red, two blue, and two yellow stickers on the faces of a cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270519/)
- [Coloring the faces of tetrahedra and cubes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413032/how-many-n-colorings-up-to-rotation-using-exactly-2-of-each-color-are-there-on)
- [Coloring the faces of a cube with $n$ colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460735/coloring-a-cube-with-4-colors)
- [Coloring the faces of a cube with exactly $M$ colors by Stirling numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240525/)
- [Color the vertices of a regular tetrahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720144/group-theory-coloring)
- [Coloring cube diagonals under rotations and Inclusion-Exclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919878/coloring-cube-additional-constraint-three-colors)
- [Proper cube colorings under rotational symmetry and the chromatic polynomial of the octahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994998/a-question-on-colouring-cubes)
- [Coloring the vertices of the icosahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166357/combination-or-permutation/)
- [Coloring vertices and edges of a tetrahedron simultaneously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324340/count-number-of-colorings-of-tetrahedron-where-colorings-are-indistinguishible)
- [Coloring vertices and faces of a cube simultaneously, color count is exact or max](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828924/)
- [Coloring the faces of a truncated tetrahedron and a truncated cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854935/)
- [Coloring the vertices of a cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858310/)
- [Coloring a snub cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545405/)
- [Coloring the faces of a truncated octahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068449/)
- [Two-colorings of the n-dimensional cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588391/)
- [Face colorings of the rhombic dodecahedron / edge colorings of the cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122575)
- [Simultaneously coloring the faces, vertices and edges of a cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4516333/)

**enumerating types of graphs**

- [Counting non-isomorphic graphs with self-loops](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41386/enumerating-graphs-with-self-loops)
- [Enumerating caterpillar graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85882/on-the-number-of-caterpillars)
- [Counting non-isomorphic graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314103/how-many-2-edge-colourings-of-k-n-are-there)
- [Counting non-isomorphic graphs, optimized version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088991/counting-multigraphs-up-to-isomorphism)
- [Counting non-isomorphic graphs, connected graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187019/)
- [Nonisomorphic graphs with 4 vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599675/why-there-are-11-non-isomorphic-graphs-of-order-4/)
- [Enumeration of centipede graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847675/what-is-the-name-of-a-graph-made-of-k-copies-of-a-4-cycle-connected-end-to-end-i)
- [Unlabled rooted trees with maximum outdegree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434908/)
- [Unlabled unrooted trees with odd degree sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104289/)
- [Counting two types of spanning subgraphs of the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151538/finding-the-spanning-subgraphs-of-a-complete-bipartite-graph/)
- [Counting two-colorings of full rooted unordered binary trees (child nodes may be swapped)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285304/)
- [Multigraphs with n labled edges or set partitions of a multiset containing two instances of n distinguishable types of elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381495/)
- [Algorithm to compute orbital chromatic polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584928/)
- [Enumerating directed graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596305)
- [Digraphs on three vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852683)

**number theory and algebra**

- [Binary matrices under dihedral symmetry of the square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387195/)
- [Binary Matrices with the symmetric group permuting rows and columns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22159/how-many-n-times-m-binary-matrices-are-there-up-to-row-and-column-permutation)
- [Matrices with the symmetric group permuting rows and columns, optimized version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056708/)
- [Matrices with the symmetric group permuting rows and columns, optimized version, worked example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113657/)
- [Partitions without duplicates by the cycle index of the set operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44806/partition-function-without-duplicates)
- [Partitions without duplicates by the cycle index of the set operator, recurrence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077769/how-many-different-ways-can-a-number-n-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-k-different-posi)
- [Partitions without duplicates by the cycle index of the set operator, closed form for fixed count](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078090/upper-bound-for-the-strict-partition-on-k-summands)
- [Counting binary structures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47792/how-many-non-isomorphic-binary-structures-on-the-set-of-n-elements)
- [Enumerating cyclic compositions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79973/is-an-algebraic-formula-for-the-number-of-cyclic-compositions-of-n-known)
- [Counting non-isomorphic relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356995/counting-non-isomorphic-relations)
- [How many $\{x,y,z\} \subset \{1,2,\ldots, 100\}$ have $x+y+z$ divisible by 3?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556924/probability-problem-on-divisibility-of-sum-by-3)
- [Subsets of size $k$ of $p$ elements whose sum is divisible by $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213139)
- [Probability that a subset of $k$ elements of $[n]$ sums to a multiple of $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417918/)
- [Probability that a multiset of $k$ elements drawn from $[n]$ sums to a multiple of $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533814/)
- [Generic algorithm for counting subsets of $n$ elements of $\{1,2,\ldots,q\}$ whose sum is divisible by some $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618420/)
- [Using the PET on Dirichlet series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363811/alternating-sum-of-multiple-zetas-equals-always-1/782850#782850)
- [Proving harmonic sum identities by applying PET to finite Dirichlet series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893565/stirling-numbers-and-harmonic-number-identities)
- [Counting Abelian groups -- a number-theoretic application of the PET](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955649/given-a-number-n-in-bbbn-in-how-many-ways-can-n-be-written-as-prod-i)
- [Cycle indices of the symmetric and alternating group and the partition function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999319/)
- [The OGF of the cycle indices of the symmetric group and the partition function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029520/)
- [Distributing red, green and blue balls into n indistinguishable bins with no empty bins and no duplicate bin contents, alternatively, factoring into distinct factors of an integer with three prime divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099238/)
- [Presence of multiples of some factor $p$ in a random subset of some size $mp$ of an integer range multiple of $mp$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153793/)
- [Connection between the OGF of the unlabeled set operator and the Newton-Girard formulae](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242641/)
- [Count of factorizations of an integer $n$ into $k$ distinct factors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250364/)
- [OGF of the unlabeled set operator and a combinatorial sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213406/)
- [multiplicative partition function, PET and OGF of the cycle index of the symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473925/)
- [unlabeled set / multiset operator sums, Stirling numbers and the OGF of the cycle index of the symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759618/burnsides-lemma-and-stirling-numbers-of-the-first-kind)
- [multiplicative partition function on products of primes, PET and OGF of the cycle index of the set operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285527/)
- [using the exponential formula to factor the polynomial $1-z^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703830/)
- [computing a closed form of the cycle index of the symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748851/)
- [a kind of set cover](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039600/)
- [the cycle index of a cyclic group generated by a given permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190130/)
- [multisets of multisets with the number of elements in a given range and a repeated element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386814/)
- [subset sum divisible by n and exponential formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417918/)

**power group enumeration**

- [Power Group Enumeration with two instances of the symmetric group by Burnside](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/number-of-classes-of-k-digit-strings-when-digit-order-and-identity-doesnt-matte)
- [Power Group Enumeration of necklaces with swappable colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121744/)
- [Counting functions $[n]\to[n]$ by Simultaneous Power Group Enumeration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416811/is-there-a-nice-characterization-of-these-classes-of-functions-on-a-set-of-n-e)
- [Power Group Enumeration on coloring the edges of a cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607956/how-many-of-all-cubes-edges-3-colorings-have-exactly-4-edges-for-each-color)
- [Power Group Enumeration of $k$-subsets of the standard deck of $52$ cards wrt. permutation of suits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864116/how-to-count-different-card-combinations-with-isomorphism)
- [Stirling numbers and Power Group Enumeration: EGF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921102/strling-numbers-and-power-group-enumeration)
- [Stirling numbers and Power Group Enumeration II: OGF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134671/getting-the-proof-of-the-generating-function-formula-for-stirling-numbers-by-st)
- [Counting sets of lottery tickets wrt. permutations of the values by the symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498954/)
- [Coloring an N by N square with Q interchangeable colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540602/)
- [Coloring an N by M square wrt row and column permutations by the symmetric group with the column permutations also acting on the colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968594/)
- [Number of sets of sequences of total length n over an alphabet of n letters with the symmetric group acting on the letters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180525/)
- [Enumerating a type of hexagonal tile](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097450/)
- [Equivalence classes of Boolean functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650624/)
- [Partitioning the multiset [1,1,2,2,...,n,n] into k submultisets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4585780/)

**necklaces and bracelets**

- [Summary sheet on necklaces and bracelets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216181)
- [Necklace problem variations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81522/problems-about-necklace)
- [Efficient coefficient extraction for certain necklaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283662/how-many-combinations-of-coloured-dots-with-restrictions)
- [Primitive necklaces, the Mobius function, and Power Group Enumeration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325957/primitive-binary-necklaces)
- [Necklaces with two colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721783/number-of-unique-sequences-with-circular-shifts)
- [Additional bracelet/necklace computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767430/labeling-the-vertices-of-a-polygon-with-0s-and-1s)
- [A garland of roses with adjacency constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792670/no-of-ways-of-forming-a-garland-using-6-red-roses-and-4-white-roses)
- [How to convert from PET to Burnside and back on a bracelet example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966349/how-many-ways-to-arrange-8-read-beads-and-32-blue-beads-into-a-necklace-such)
- [Cookbook type explanation of a necklace enumeration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181688/number-of-distinct-necklaces-with-12-beads-each-bead-red-or-blue-rotations-d)
- [Two-coloring a necklace on $2n$ beads where opposite beads must have different colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475582/)
- [Another introductory necklace example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1575862/)
- [More necklace computations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604188/)
- [A bracelet of sixteen beads and two colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700345/)
- [Necklaces with the forbidden pattern 110](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812920/)
- [Simultaneous action on vertices and edges of a hexagonal bracelet (dihedral symmetry)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833081/)
- [Primitive necklaces, the general formula, with number-theoretic proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852745/)
- [Bracelet with two instances of each of N colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024406).
- [Necklaces and bracelets with ten slots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2146914/)
- [Necklaces with at most some number of colors where adjacent colors must be different](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164399/)
- [Necklaces with two instances of each of n colors where adjacent slots must be different](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209954/)
- [Coloring a board with toroidal symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506511/)
- [Necklace / bracelet documented example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901112/unique-necklace-from-6-beads)
- [Necklaces from musical notes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968305/)
- [Extracting a closed form for a type of bracelet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998245/)
- [Coloring necklace / bracelet edges and vertices simultaneously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979734/)
- [Necklaces with k colors of beads with n/k beads each](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109913/)
- [Coloring bracelets with swappable colors, generating functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191361/)
- [Coloring bracelets properly, generating functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194602/)
- [Coloring a twelve-necklace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213424/)
- [Necklaces of n colors with three instances each and no monochrome three-sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464640/)

**miscellaneous**

- [Orbit counting of permutation matrices under rotation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151421/)
- [Introductory commentary on Burnside](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165184/burnsides-lemma)
- [Coloring squares in an $n\times n$ array](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570003/how-many-unique-patterns-exist-for-a-nxn-grid)
- [Omitting pieces from a $3×3×3$ array of cubes / stacking constituent cubes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579623/cube-stack-problem)
- [The ordinary generating function of the cycle index of the symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603527/number-of-ways-powers-of-2-sum-up-specific-values)
- [Coloring the edges of a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706552/using-burnsides-lemma-understanding-the-intuition-and-theory)
- [Binary matrices with a fixed number of entries per column under row and column permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616834/how-many-arrays-with-crossed-cells-order-of-rows-columns-irrelevant)
- [Color exactly two squares in a $2n\times 2n$ square array](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744161/counting-shaded-squares/)
- [Permuting $2^n$ binary numbers by flipping bits, number of functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764344/permutation-group-of-2n-binary-numbers)
- [Coloring a triangular array with $n$ levels under rotational symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772981/i-am-confused-on-how-to-solve-a-question-by-using-burnsides-lemma)
- [Coloring the H-shaped tree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912540/how-many-ways-are-there-to-color-the-h-shaped-tree-with-3-colors-such-that-e)
- [How many ways to choose three coins of four types?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1075055/)
- [3 Coloring a Baton of n Bands](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198773/3-coloring-a-baton-of-n-bands)
- [Combinatorial problem on bridge deals with spot cards not being distinguishable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234919/)
- [Introductory example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567689)
- [Polya and Burnside when all of the elements being distributed into the slots must be present at least once and Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571284/)
- [Painting the edges of the Petersen graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711016/permutation-group-and-cycle-index-question-regarding-peterson-graph/)
- [Coloring a 5x5 grid and inclusion-exclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761762/)
- [Counting permutations with a given cycle structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921804/)
- [Coloring a cross-shaped structure embedded in a 5x5 grid and inclusion-exclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228311/)
- [Symmetries of the five-by-five square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730587)
- [Counting multisets of mutisets by multiset cycle indices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856255/)
- [Counting chemical compounds on a hexagonal carbon atom lattice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162759/)
- [Colorings of Kn with an edge removed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545391/)
- [The product of two cycle indices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923907/)
- [Binary n X n X n tensor under rotational symmetry (cube)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182230/)
- [Enumerating orbits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252561/)
- [Placing points on a square grid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349648/)

Comment: Let's try to keep these in order by post ID number so that it is easy to avoid duplicates.

Comment: How would I create a tag "Polya/Burnside" on MSE and if possible re-tag these questions automatically?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Tags are created simply by [adding the new tag to a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). When creating tag, it is good to write also a [tag-wiki/tag-excerpt](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-wikis/info) for the new tag. It's up to you whether you discuss creating the new tag on meta first, or whether you create tag without such a discussion. But I think that it is a good thing that those questions will be bumped when retagged - other users will be alerted about the new tag by this and if they disagree, they can react on meta.

Comment: This is one topic (Polya-Burnside) rather than several. The questions on coloring cubes and counting necklaces get asked all the time over and over again. That's why MJD suggested we make this list.

Answer (score 22):

More for my own sake than anything else. Integration duplicates tend to be quite hard to find due to the large amount of symbols in titles. Here is a short list of some famous integrals that pop up periodically

#### [Integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration) [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration)

- The Gaussian integral: [Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx = \dfrac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2?lq=1). More proofs [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf).
- The Dirichlet integral: [Evaluating the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \ dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2) This question has many generalizations. See for instance [Proof of $\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 \mathrm dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/proof-of-int-0-infty-left-frac-sin-xx-right2-mathrm-dx-frac-pi2?lq=1) or [A sine integral $\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin x }{x }\right)^n\,\mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307510/a-sine-integral-int-0-infty-left-frac-sin-x-x-rightn-mathrmdx?rq=1).
- The standard $\int \mathrm{d}x/(1+x^n)$.

  - *Definite:* [How can I compute the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{1+t^4}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43457/how-can-i-compute-the-integral-int-0-infty-fracdt1t4).
  - *Indefinite* [Evaluating $\int \frac{1}{{x^4+1}} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333611/evaluating-int-frac1x41-dx?lq=1).
  - *General Indefinite* [Improper integration involving complex analytic arguments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255875/improper-integration-involving-complex-analytic-arguments)
  - *General Indefinite* [Closed form for $\int_0^\infty {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{1 + {x^m}}}dx }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx)
- Serret's integral: [Evaluate the integral: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} \mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155941/evaluate-the-integral-int-01-frac-lnx1x21-mathrm-dx). See also [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SerretsIntegral.html) for references or [Putnam 2005 A5](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~dale/putnam/2005.pdf) for further proofs.
- Fresnel integrals: [Some way to integrate $\sin(x^2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251083/some-way-to-integrate-sinx2) or [Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \sin x^2\, dx$ with real methods?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187729/evaluating-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-with-real-methods?lq=1). A couple more proofs can be found [here](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/loya/papers/LoyaMathMag.pdf).
- The Poisson kernel integral: [A question in Complex Analysis $\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-2r\cos x +r^2)\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352046/a-question-in-complex-analysis-int-02-pi-log1-2r-cos-x-r2-dx)
- Wallis integrals: Could not find this question, here is a [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) though.
- The logarithmic sine integral: [Computing the integral of $\log(\sin x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37829/computing-the-integral-of-log-sin-x) or [Evaluate: $\int_0^{\pi} \ln \left( \sin \theta \right) d\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354795/evaluate-int-0-pi-ln-left-sin-theta-right-d-theta?lq=1)
- Integrals solved by symmetry:

  -- Putnam 1986 5B: [A Putnam Integral $\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)}\,dx}{\sqrt{\ln(9-x)} + \sqrt{\ln(x+3)}}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957510/a-putnam-integral-int-24-frac-sqrt-ln9-x-dx-sqrt-ln9-x-sqrt)

  -- Various forms of $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin^ax \,\mathrm{d}x}{\cos^ax + \sin^ax}$: [How to compute $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^3 t}{\sin^3 t+\cos^3 t}dt$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82489/how-can-i-calculate-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin3-t-sin3-t-cos3-tdt)

  -- The $\tan^a(x)$ integral: [Integrate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1+\tan^\alpha{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605673/integrate-int-0-pi-2-frac11-tan-alphax-mathrmdx)

Comment: Perhaps we could add [Evaluate $\int\frac1{1+x^n}dx$ for $n\in\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999869/evaluate-int-frac11xndx-for-n-in-mathbb-r) to the list?

Comment: You can search by MathJaX, the problem becomes how many ways are there to create the same thing.

Answer (score 17):

There ought to be an entry for the [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) / [limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limit) classic:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n = \exp x$$

I found these posts on it so far:

- [About $\lim \left(1+\frac {x}{n}\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/358830/43351)
- [Intuitive proofs that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/365029/43351)
- [Proving $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty } \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=\text{e}^x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420018/43351)
- [$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{r}{n})^n$ is equal to ${e^{r}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115863/43351)
- [Why isn't $\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}$ equal to $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/370125/43351)
- [Show that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left( 1-\frac{\lambda}{x} \right)^x = e^{-\lambda}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/524957/43351)

which I've ordered from most to least suited for [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) status (after a suitable amount of editing). There are probably more, but I couldn't find them by searching the site.

(I've posted this answer because it is not obvious which one of the above should get [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) status.)

Comment: You can add it yourself. Please feel free to do so. Pick one as the representative, and tag that as FAQ.  I also downvoted this answer so that this question is periodically bumped up (no answer with > 0 votes).

Answer (score 14):

### Frequent duplicate induction problems

- [Partial sum of geometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658992/proving-the-geometric-sum-formula-by-induction)
- [Sum of binomial coefficients is $2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734900/proof-by-induction-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-sum-k-0n-n-k-2n)
- [$2^n > n^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263825/proof-of-n2-leq-2n)
- [$n! > 2^n$ for $n \geq 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140396)

  - [$n! > 3^n$ for $n \geq 6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466530) or maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480832).
  - For $n! > 4^n$ and above, currently there are only isolated posts and not a network to be made.
- [If $n>2$, then $n! < n^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260233)
- [If $n>2$, then $(n!)^2>n^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640602/show-that-if-n2-then-n2nn)
- [$1 + 2 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn) (Maybe there is a better duplicate that focuses more on a proof by induction rather than just any proof--[this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206645/showing-12-cdotsn-fracnn12-by-induction-stuck-on-inductive-step) may be a good choice, for example)
- [Every $n > 1$ can be written as a product of primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833746/complete-induction-proof-that-every-n-1-can-be-written-as-a-product-of-prime)
- [$n^2 > n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725443/proof-by-induction-that-n2-ge-n-for-all-n-in-mathbbz)
- [$1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct)
- [Bernoulli's inequality $(1 + x)^n \ge 1 + nx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670355/prove-if-x-ge-1-then-1xn-ge-1nx-every-n-ge-1/670381)

Answer (score 11):

## Hypergeometric/Summation Identities [summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summation)

Rather than have these broken up among algebra-precalculus, proof by induction, combinatorics, etc. I am gathering them all in one place.

---

#### Faulhaber identities (sums of powers)

$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ (triangle numbers)

- [What is the term for a factorial type operation, but with summation instead of products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60578)
- [Proof that $1+2+3+4+\cdots+n = \frac{n\times(n+1)}2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260)

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ (pyramid numbers)

- [How do I come up with a function to count a pyramid of apples?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24521)
- [Sum of First $n$ Squares Equals $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080)
- [How to get to the formula for the sum of squares of first n numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183316)
- [how can one find the value of the expression, $(1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188602)
- [How to calculate the sum of $(n-1)^2+(n-2)^2+...+1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374886)

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)^2$ (sum of cubes)

- With Induction: [Proving $1^3+ 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171)
- Without Induction: [Proving the identity $\sum_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \big(\sum_{k=1}^n k\big)^2$ without induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482)

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^p$ (general formula)

- [Finite Sum of Power?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155166)
- [Methods to compute $\sum_{k=1}^nk^p$ without Faulhaber's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035188)

---

#### Geometric series/(Generalized) Binomial Theorem

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k$

- [How to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom {n}{k}=0 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933636/how-to-prove-that-sum-k-0n-1k-binom-nk-0)

$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^N x^n = \frac{1 - x^{N + 1}}{1-x}$ (geometric series)

- [Values of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^N x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023)

$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty (n+1)x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ (derivative of geometric series)

- [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732)

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k} x^n = \frac1{(1-x)^{k + 1}}$ (Negative Binomial Theorem)

- [Closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k} x^n$ (Negative Binomial Theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1568198)

$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k \binom{n}{k} = n2^{n-1}$ (derivative of binomial theorem)

- [How to prove this binomial identity $\sum_{r=0}^n {r {n \choose r}} = n2^{n-1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7757)

---

### Vandermonde-like identities

$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{a}{k} \binom{b}{n - k} = \binom{a + b}{n}$ (Vandermonde's identity)

- [How to prove Vandermonde's Identity: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{R}{k}\binom{M}{n-k}=\binom{R+M}{n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337923)

$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} (-1)^k\binom{a}{k} \binom{b}{n - k} = \left[x^n\right](1-x)^a(1+x)^b$ (alternating Vandermonde sum)

- [Alternating sign Vandermonde convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94501)

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$ (special case of Vandermonde)

- [Combinatorial proof of summation of $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}^2= {2n \choose n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583)

---

#### Other

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}\binom{k}{n}=\binom{N+1}{n+1}$ (Hockey-Stick Identity)

- [Proof of the hockey stick/Zhu Shijie identity $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794)
- [Prove $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{i+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k}{k}$ (a.k.a. Hockey-Stick Identity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451)
- [Induction proof concerning a sum of binomial coefficients: $\sum_{j=m}^n\binom{j}{m}=\binom{n+1}{m+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74844)

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=4^n$ (convolution of central binomial coefficients)

- [Identity for convolution of central binomial coefficients: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}=2^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971)

Answer (score 10):

## [Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+probability) [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability)

- "Two Children Puzzle / Boy Born on a Tuesday" and variants:

  - [In a family with two children, what are the chances, if one of the children is a girl, that both children are girls?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15055)
  - [New Two Children problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33566)
  - [Boy Born on a Tuesday - is it just a language trick?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400)
- A "liar paradox" variant: [Multiple-choice question about the probability of a random answer to itself being correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76491/)
- [Bertrand's box paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132722)
- Expectation as tail probability (complementary CDF) integral/sum.

  - Continuous (generalized to any $E[X^p]$ in the answer): [Explain why $E(X) = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X (t)) \, dt$ for every nonnegative random variable $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841).
  - Discrete:  [Find the Mean for Non-Negative Integer-Valued Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845)
  - Measure-theoretic treatment: [Rigorous proof that $\int_{\Omega}X\;dP=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\;dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402640)
- Probability for roots of a quadratic equation to be real, where the coefficients are iid random variables with distribution:
- [discrete uniform$\{1,2, 3,4,5,6\}$ from standard die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120083), whereas [322939](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322939) is also a good candidate.
  <sup>There are isolated posts regarding discrete uniform of different ranges, and continuous uniform, exponential distribution, etc.</sup>
- Coupon collector's problem [coupon-collector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coupon-collector)

  - standard version

    - expectation: [Expected time to roll all $1$ through $6$ on a die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905) (duplicated at [calculating expected number of packets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782769/))
    - probability distribution: [Probability distribution in the coupon collector's problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379525/)
  - only desired items

    - expectation: [Coupon collector problem with partial collection of a specific set of coupons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912436) (duplicated at [Pile of cards - Probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682695))
    - probability distribution: [Coupon Collector Prob Variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909313) (duplicated at [Coupon collector - Chance of collecting desired coupons but not a full set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488656))
  - batches / groups / packets

    - fixed number per packet, distinct coupons:

      - expectation: [Expected number of times a set of 10 integers (selected from 1-100) is selected before all 100 are seen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375470) (duplicated at [Probability - Expected number of draws to get all 52 cards at least once drawing in groups of size n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147576) and [Expected number of games so that every player has been an Imposter in Among Us](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840627))
      - probability distribution: [Sample all elements from a set at least once, with replacement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3396686)
    - fixed number per packet, repetitions allowed:

      - expectation: [Coupon Collector Problem with Batched Selections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131664) (duplicated at [How to calculate the expected value of the coupon collector problem if we are collecting the coupons in groups of k?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600817))
      - probability distribution: [Coupon Collector's problem, version with multiple coupons in a box](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595993)
    - random number per packet, distinct coupons: [coupon collector problem with groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729848/)
  - unequal probabilities:

    - mean and variance: [Coupon collector's problem: mean and variance in number of coupons to be collected to complete a set (unequal probabilities)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453965/)
    - probability distribution: [Probability that N i.i.d. draws from a multinomial distribution have made all events appear](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410002)

---

## [Statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+statistics) [statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)

- Upper tail inequality for the standard normal distribution:

  - [Proof of upper-tail inequality for standard normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28751),
  - [Proof of an estimate for the tail of a normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74151/)
- Normal approximation (CLT) for discrete Binomial: ... (to be continued... okay, this task is more complicated than expected)

Comment: About the topic `Expectation as tail probability (complementary CDF) integral/sum`. (1) the continuous case, other candidates I've considered are two older posts: [63756](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63756), which answer generalizes to "any" $E[g(X)]$, and [64186](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64186) that is highly upvoted with several good answers. I went with [172841](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841) because of existing links. It seems that for a while some users agreed to link many duplicates to this one.

Comment: (2) the discrete case, there’s another strong candidate [74186](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74186) (better than a [runner up](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457602) that is more recent) that also has two posts closed to it as duplicates (not just linked). I went with [843845](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845) because there are more content and more "natural links". There’s also [660185](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660185) that has one post closed to it as a duplicate.

Comment: (3) I’m not sure about having a separate sub-category of measure-theoretic treatment. As I went through the process of dropping comments for all the duplicates I found, I barely linked them to what I chose, the post [402640](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402640). In other words, I'm not sure it really deserves the tag `faq`.

Comment: (4) there are posts with extension (sort of easy) to non-negative r.v. (with absolute value or split integral). I’m not sure if they should have a separate "mother post" here and none of them seem to standout as much better than the others for such purpose. Currently I’ve identified five: [1349624](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349624), [1350577](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350577), [1427801](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427801), [1489123](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489123), and [2300167](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300167).

Comment: The probabilities for hitting either of two boundaries in a simple symmetric one-dimensional random walk are treated in many posts, but I haven't been able to identify a canonical one with a general treatment that would be a good original for all duplicates.

Comment: I just closed a question about this by referring to these five questions, none of which seems optimal: [3497645](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497645), [145705](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145705), [4253962](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253962), [3501693](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501693), [4583814](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4583814). If you find a better fit, please add it to the answer above.

Answer (score 8):

There are some standard questions in [general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology):

- [A continuous bijection from a compact space to a $T_2$ space is always a homeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256917/a-continuous-bijection-from-a-compact-space-to-a-t-2-space-is-always-a-homeomo)
- [Compact set in a Hausdorff topological space is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/how-to-prove-that-a-compact-set-in-a-hausdorff-topological-space-is-closed)
- [Compact set might not be closed in a general topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239998/compact-sets-are-closed)
- [No continuous bijection between an interval $[0,1]$ and a square $[0,1]^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510573/is-there-a-continuous-bijection-between-an-interval-and-a-square-0-1-mapsto)
- [Continuous image of compact sets are compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26514/continuous-image-of-compact-sets-are-compact)
- Compactness of a metric space in terms of their continuous functions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114123/compactness-of-m-d-in-terms-of-continuous-functions-fm-to-mathbb-r), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668905/if-every-real-valued-continuous-function-is-bounded-on-x-metric-space-then)

#### Book recommendations:

- [Best book of topology for beginner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520)
- [Can anybody recommend me a topology textbook?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150556)
- [Choosing a text for a First Course in Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903)
- [Introductory book on Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94242)
- [Reference for general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118190) (Related, but not the same)

Answer (score 8):

Questions about [[irreducible-polynomials]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irreducible-polynomials) concerning generic methods:

- [Methods to see if a polynomial is irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/methods-to-see-if-a-polynomial-is-irreducible)
- [How to choose correct strategy for irreducibility testing in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544570/strategy-for-irreducibility-testing-in-mathbbzx?noredirect=1)
- [Checking irreducibility of polynomials over number fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607842/checking-irreducibility-of-polynomials-over-number-fields?rq=1)
- [Techniques for checking irreducibility over the rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589375/techniques-for-checking-irreducibility-over-the-rationals?rq=1)
- [Does irreducibility in $\mathbb Q[X]$ always imply the irreducibility in $\mathbb Z[X]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963960/does-irreducibility-in-mathbb-qx-always-imply-the-irreducibility-in-mathb)
- [If $q(X)$ is reducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$, then it's reducible in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$ for every prime $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830109/if-qx-is-reducible-in-mathbb-zx-then-its-reducible-in-mathbb-z-px)
- [Does irreducibility in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ imply irreducibility in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606220/irreducibility-in-f-p-implies-irreducibility-in-mathbbq)
- [Prove that the polynomial $x^nf(1/x)$ with reverted coefficients is also irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963477/prove-that-the-given-polynomial-is-irreducible-polynomial-over-q)
- [Motivation for Eisenstein Criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23874/motivation-for-eisenstein-criterion)
- [Explaining Newton Polygon for proving irreducibility of polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ in elementary way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671738/explaining-newton-polygon-in-elementary-way)
- When is the polynomial $x^n-a$ irreducible: [the result and links](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133581/11619), [on-site proof in the case $n$ prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/403924/11619).

Comment: I am sure I have missed some generic frequently referenced methods, or there might better candidate, anyone please update accordingly...

Answer (score 5):

A couple of analysis exercises that appear frequently:

- [prove that $f'(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f'(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx)
- [if $f'(x)\rightarrow L$ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$, $-\infty \leq L \leq \infty $ then $ f(x)/x \rightarrow L $ as $x \rightarrow \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044668/if-fx-rightarrow-l-as-x-rightarrow-infty-infty-leq-l-leq-infty)

Answer (score 2):

## [Continued Fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+probability) [continued-fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continued-fractions)

- Pell Equations:

  - [algebra direct connect pell eqn soln $(p_{nk},q_{nk})$ with $(p_n + q_n\sqrt{D})^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749487/algebra-direct-connect-pell-eqn-soln-p-nk-q-nk-with-p-n-q-n-sqrtd)