# Is it possible to make a reference request within MSE questions/answers?

Tags: feature-request

I've seen questions such as:

> What are the best real analysis books that take a standard approach to some of the basic theorems.

Is it ok to make a reference-request question asking about the best questions/answers in MSE for a specific topic?

Comment: What is the motivation to do so, as opposed to opening up [applicable tags and sorting by votes](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus?sort=votes&pagesize=50)? (just wondering)

Comment: Well. It would because people with more experience could indicate what they think is best/insightul.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from there, then...

Comment: @anorton What you mean?

Comment: Sorry.  I meant that I can understand why just opening the tags is not sufficient compared to a question.  (Although I do tend to agree with the answer in that it's a bit meta-ish)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds meta-ish. FAQ says that Math.SE is [not for questions about Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq).

There is a meta thread  [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1868/75064)  in which "canonical" answers to frequently posed questions are collected. The "question" in that thread is the categorized list of links, and "answers" include suggestions for a new category and invitations for items to be included in that category. If you are interested in collecting canonical answers in a particular category, you can propose it there.