# Canonical duplicate for periodic sequence formula questions?

Tags: discussion

This question was on the hot network questions today: [Function which creates the sequence 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678895/function-which-creates-the-sequence-1-2-3-1-2-3/2679025)

While it certainly has some pedantic value, it's not very interesting mathematically and, more importantly, [it's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060930/formula-for-a-periodic-sequence-of-1s-and-1s-with-period-5) [been](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564617/formula-for-periodic-sequence) [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559992/periodic-sequence-of-repeating-numbers) [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2106449/formula-for-nth-term-in-sequence/2106515). Those are just the ones I could find with a quick google search; I'm sure many more have been asked as I recall seeing them. They aren't exactly the same, but close enough to be considered duplicates - the answer is invariable a simple arithmetic formula using modulo, or, if the asker forbids that, a work-around using floor, ceiling, or sine/cosine.

Is there a single duplicate that we have for these questions and if not, should there be?

Comment: I saved this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790642/general-formula-for-the-1-5-19-65-211-sequence/1790666#1790666) from closing for the purpose of addressing similar concerns.

Comment: A big list of [abstract duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions) are recorded. I think it is a very useful resources (though it seems not many are using it). I cannot find your question there. I think [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678895/function-which-creates-the-sequence-1-2-3-1-2-3/2679025) could be added to the thread, under sequence/series.