# Editing the list of abstract duplicates

Tags: discussion, editing, exact-duplicates, meta

I'd like to add some content to the meta post [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868).

The entry will be under `Probability` and is going to be titled something like "Expectation as tail probability integral (sum)". This is triggered by the two posts today ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993758), and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993779)) along with some more I've come across (that are neither closed nor commented/linked as duplicates).

**My question is this:**

Should I directly edit the question post? Or should I split the currently very short sections `Probability` along with `Statistics` out to a separate answer post?

---

It makes me feel a bit uncomfortable editing the whole **question** post (where most topics currently reside). However, I do see that the **answer** posts that some users have added in the past few years since the first conception of the list *might* have made the list less organized.

(I'm not questioning the good faith and hard work that was put into those answer posts.)

This issue of mine of course has been discussed in the comments ([this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#comment6390_1868) and the several that follow), but I don't see a definitely argument for either way.

A good portion of the work (of identifying duplicates) is now finished, and I'm about to first edit [the meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) then start to comment under about $20$ posts (duplicates which are unlinked yet) to establish the links.

I understand that everything I do can be further corrected or rolled back, but I still would like to know the appropriate course of action before making any changes to that meta post.

---

The actual process of establishing the duplicates network/links (for the topic "expectation as tail integral"), if are to be discussed, should perhaps be a separate meta post. Just for the record, I have not missed [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841) which for a while was the "target" duplicates linked to.

Comment: I haven't checked out your edits, but good faith additions to that thread are IMHO all welcome.  If there are any imperfections in your additions, others can further polish them. Thanks for participating in site maintenance!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Haven't started the edit yet, as I'm being cautious right now. I'll try my best in keeping up with the standards. Thanks.