# List of answer templates

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions, big-list

I've created this post with the same purpose as the [List of comment templates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4925/167197) post, although I imagine it'll be far less useful. There are a few questions on the [Unanswered Questions Queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered) only because their answer is *yes* or *no* or something analogously unworthy of making a post. I want to collect some reasonable answers to copy/paste for such questions here.

To facilitate easy copying, if your comment contains links and/or formatting, please enclose the whole text between single [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) characters <kbd>`</kbd> to type your answer verbatim `like this`.`

---

Here's a list of examples harvested from questions I've answered that these templates could be used for. Most of them have better answers than the templates below, but having an answer that says something like "yes, you're right," doesn't keep someone from answering the question better later. I'd just rather these questions not stagnate in the [Unanswered Questions Queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered) just because their answer is yes/no.

[Confused about which area bounded by the curve I'm calculating](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712593/confused-about-which-area-bounded-by-the-curve-im-calculating)

[Bergman's Diamond Lemma: do these rules lead to a normal form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137005/bergmans-diamond-lemma-do-these-rules-lead-to-a-normal-form)

[Is every connected, finite, undirected graph in which all vertices are degree two a cycle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047426/is-every-connected-finite-undirected-graph-in-which-all-vertices-are-degree-tw)

[Proof of arithmetical identities $-(-m)=m$ and $-0=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137197/proof-of-arithmetical-identities-m-m-and-0-0)

[Is my understanding of when a graph is planar (or not) correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048393/is-my-understanding-of-when-a-graph-is-planar-or-not-correct)

[Ore's "Graphs and Their Uses" Problem Set 1.5, Problem 2 ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786465/ores-graphs-and-their-uses-problem-set-1-5-problem-2)

[Two interview questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710490/two-interview-questions)

[True? "A rectangle is a subset of a circle if and only if all its vertices are in the circle (or its boundary)."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935727/true-a-rectangle-is-a-subset-of-a-circle-if-and-only-if-all-its-vertices-are-i)

[Bipartite Graph Typo in "Modern Graph Theory" by Bollobas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044314/bipartite-graph-typo-in-modern-graph-theory-by-bollobas)

[Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $Y=\{1,2,3,4\}$, and $Z=\{1,2\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006132/let-x-1-2-3-y-1-2-3-4-and-z-1-2)

[Injective mapping onto a subgroup of a finite group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340094/injective-mapping-onto-a-subgroup-of-a-finite-group)

[Why isn't there necessarily a direct sum of rings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209200/why-isnt-there-necessarily-a-direct-sum-of-rings)

[What's the term to describe a morphism that isn't a composite of morphisms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016417/whats-the-term-to-describe-a-morphism-that-isnt-a-composite-of-morphisms)

[Translating the information from a word problem into a function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410771/translating-the-information-from-a-word-problem-into-a-function)

[Integration technique of writing $\int_0^{\infty}$ as $\int_0^1 + \int_1^{\infty}$ and using the substitution $\frac{1}{x} \leftrightarrow u$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2060187/integration-technique-of-writing-int-0-infty-as-int-01-int-1-infty)

Comment: I am rather strictly against giving such answers. Usually better answers are possible. By extension I am against this thread (even though it is rather thought out).

Comment: @quid For some questions there's a better answer, but I often don't know what to say besides "yeah, you're right." The reason I had my templates below typed up were because there are so many of these in the Unanswered Questions Queue, when they really shouldn't be. Like, even if there are better answers, now one is typing them up for old unanswered questions. And posting these template answers doesn't preclude another user from coming along and typing up a better answer sometime (in which case I hope that user flags the template answer for deletion).

Comment: Could you show some examples of such questions? Also how good are the questions? In any case, I think you should raise the discussion if this is considered as desirable first, and only then post templates for what are arguable posts that could be flagged as NAA.

Comment: @quid I've added links to a bunch of example question to the body of the post. Some of them definitely aren't good questions and could probably be deleted. Most of the answers have something besides "Yes, you're right," but I would have written that there only because of the "There's a better answer than 'yeah, you're right'" guideline, but really what I added isn't useful. Also, diving into my answer history, the majority of posts I responded to that were in the Unanswered Questions Queue unnecessarily were because they were answered in the comments. But you don't need a template to fix those

Comment: I think it is useful you did not answer with the templates. I clicked on about five posts so far. Further *identical* answers are a problem specifically. Posting such might trigger protection mechanisms. (That's not the case for comments.)

Comment: I take it the goal here is a bit differentfrom  [the list of generalizations of common questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1868/11619). Linking it mostly to help locating them from each other. Not sure how useful this is given that the people who really should consult that other list rarely do so.  Anyway, I agree 100% that template answers like those below SHOULD ALWAYS BE CW.

Comment: For these types of questions, I usually answer “yes/no”, **and also** give extra context, some guidance, alternate proofs, etc. I think this is what should be done in general.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, your thoughts/proof is correct

Because there are a bunch of proof-verification type questions where the OP's proof is absolutely correct, and users have said and upvoted this fact in the comments.

> #### Yes, this is correct.
>
> <sup>I'm posting this CW answer so that users who **confidently** concur have something to vote on, and so this question doesn't stagnate in the [Unanswered Questions Queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). If however anyone would like to write a more substantial response to the question, please downvote this answer and post your own.</sup>

`### Yes, this is correct.`

`<sup> I'm posting this CW answer so that users who **confidently** concur have something to vote on, and so this question doesn't stagnate in the [Unanswered Questions Queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). If however anyone would like to write a more substantial response to the question, please downvote this answer and post your own.
</sup>`

Answer (score 2):

### There is no (term/phrase/name) for the (idea/object) you're describing

This one is for questions that are like "*Here's this mathematical object. Is there a common name for such a thing?*"

> #### No, no such thing exists.
>
> <sup>This post exists so that users who **confidently** concur that the answer to the question is "*No*" have an answer to vote on. If however anyone has an affirmative response to the question, please downvote this and post the answer.</sup>

`### No, no such thing exists.`

`<sup> This post exists so that users who **confidently** concur that the answer to the question is "*No*" have an answer to vote on. If however anyone has an affirmative response to the question, please downvote this and post the answer.`