# Encouraging duplicate hunters

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, badges

There are more and more duplicates on this site, but sometimes it is time consuming to find an earlier source. Now, there is a variety of moderation badges for editing, voting, reviewing, raising helpful flags, but I didn't find any badge for encouraging duplicate hunters. Would it be a good idea to create such a badge?

P.S. I hope this question is not a duplicate...

Comment: Some related posts on [meta.se]: [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466) (and [other posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/37466)), [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90620) (and [the posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/90620).) The proposal about reputation for finding duplicates was marked ([meta-tag:status-declined]).

Comment: While I wish people could be more motivated to be diligent about this, I'm afraid incentives would get them to "do the thing" and not necessarily "do the right thing."

Comment: I'd be pointless without duplicates ...

Comment: The entire nature of the incentive is that it provides a reward for doing the right thing to the point where you can decide whether you want to continue doing it afterwards.  Personally, I'm sorry the proposal was declined eight years ago and I would respectfully ask that it be reconsidered.  As a relatively new user, I'd like to be able to demonstrate my mastery of tags that I am a master at, but that's hard to do in modern times when have of the questions that I could answer I flag as a dupe.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate%3A1  shows the ones that have been marked already ...

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions?r=SearchResults

Comment: flagging as duplicate for the flagging badges ...