# How to quickly find duplicate questions which are not exact duplicates.

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, search

Some moderators are able to find duplicate posts which are not exact duplicates. That is to say even in the case where the question is posed completely differently but the solution uses similar methods and techniques they can find a similar question rapidly.

I am focusing on the point that the question is posed differently because in the case where the question is posed in the same way text based search can be used to find the duplicate, which I understand.

I am interested in learning some methods and techniques on the site that I am unfamiliar with, or rather if these moderators just have a good memory and a greater familiarity with the site.

Comment: I thought I purposely put the tag duplicate and not the tag exact duplicate. Maybe those two tags are really the same?

Comment: Your suspicion is [correct](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/exact-duplicates/synonyms).  Searching for similar Questions can be a challenge, and for topics that come up frequently we have adopted a notion of "abstract duplicates" per [this meta Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions) and its links.

Comment: Also visit the chat room [In search of a question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question).

Comment: What could be useful method to search depends on the question. Sometimes it helps to check the frequent tab of some tag. Sometimes various math-aware serach engines might help. You might check things mentioned here: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) Other [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/29265) might be useful, too.

Comment: If one reads a question and recalls having answered a similar question, then it's much easier, as the haystack is much smaller — namely, the set of one's answers.

Comment: Many duplicates are not found by moderators but by normal users of this site. You can query the Stack Exchange Data Explorer for the most active duplicate voters: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/880325/top-duplicate-closevoters .