# Similar questions about the misunderstanding of limits of products

Tags: discussion

I've been noticing that we get a lot of questions like  [Why do I get two different answers while doing this simple limit math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653309/why-do-i-get-two-different-answers-while-doing-this-simple-limit-math)

It's basically the traditional thing where people don't understand where you need both limits to exist for the product of the functions/sequences to exist. I'm thinking about in the future when I see this sort of question, I'll post above link and say the traditional "Does this answer your question?"

Does this sound like a good idea? Also, would questions that are like the above be considered a duplicate?

Comment: Have you checked the [list of generalisations of common questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalisations-of-common-questions)? These questions on limits might have already been covered.

Comment: Someone should create a FAQ question.