# What question (or answer) of your own are you most proud of on MathSE?

Tags: discussion, celebration, rant

I'm sure many of them will go over my head but have you posted a question or answer on MathSE that you were really proud of, and if so what was it?

I recently just had my first question that, and I may have been looking in the wrong places but, I could not find anything on via Google & MathSE which was:
[How to tell when a degree sequence has a unique unlabelled graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4804823/989186)

I was just so surprised to not find anything on what otherwise seems to be such a simple (at least simply worded) question. Between providing the context of how this question popped up for me, having some solid understanding that there are cases but unable to find the key/pattern to when the answer is true, and the awesome answer that was given. The whole process has brought me so much joy.

This just feels like such a big milestone for me because I would say my experience on MathSE has otherwise been the complete opposite. Typically my questions, coming from some problem from an intro class I am taking mixed together with my terrible mathematics foundation, tend to, mostly rightfully, be not well received. But for a while it has led me to become overly worried about asking too elementary of questions which is hard when taking such intro classes sometimes.

This coinciding with me very recently being able to actually contribute [my first MathSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4785014/989186) must be a sign. Hopefully one that means there's plenty of good questions (and answers) to come from me which I honestly never expected. I am so genuinely happy though right now haha.

Comment: I've noticed there definitely is some elitism amongst some users, both on here and Stack Overflow. Why they feel the need to condescend to people who are less experienced is beyond me. Maybe they do it to feel better about themselves through thinking their experience in STEM makes them better than others, or to gatekeep, or... idk. If you see something you find hurtful, you could report it and move on. STEM isn't the only field that has a lot of these kinds of people. I've seen the same attitudes back when I was in a marching band in high school.

Answer (score 4):

My question with high upvotes is [Evaluation of a continued fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351333/442)

My answers with high upvotes are

[Prove that every convex function is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/615161/442)

and

[In classical logic, why is $(p\Rightarrow q)$ True if both $p$ and $q$ are False?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48202/442)

Another nice answer:

[Is there a function with the property $f(n)=f^{(n)}(0)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91927/442)

Comment: I think it's tied to people downvoting OP's question overall, though I'm not sure why. For silly social questions still tied directly to the site like this and asked in good faith, I don't think it's a big issue (and I find it a little refreshing as a change of pace from the usual support or misplaced questions).

Answer (score 2):

[This answer about continued fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749487/algebra-direct-connect-pell-eqn-soln-p-nk-q-nk-with-p-n-q-n-sqrtd/2752161?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C23.4532#2752161) is the best work that I've ever done.  To the best of my knowledge, I provided a direct proof of an already proven theorem, where the previous proof was *indirect* (but still valid).

I consider [this answer about a Polya theory related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464640/placing-different-colors-of-indistinguishable-balls-around-a-circle/4464820?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C15.2187#4464820) my second best work.  In the answer, in the section on the computation of $~T_0,~$ I provided enough details to allow a reader who is totally ignorant of Polya theory to understand the solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out your work on the continued fraction for square root of an integer.  I recently discovered that there are a lot of Questions that relate to this topic, so perhaps a guide to various aspects of those special continued fractions should be included in the abstract duplicates meta post.

Comment: @hardmath What abstract duplicates meta post?

Comment: Wow, a lot of the continued fractions stuff goes over my head. But that is one detailed and thorough answer. :)

Comment: See [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalisations-of-common-questions).

Comment: @hardmath Per your suggestion, and considering your comment that MathSE has many questions on [continued fractions or Pell Equations], I have initiated a *Continued Fractions* answer to the List of Generalizations of Common Questions.  If (for example) you (or anyone) feels that it would be better to use the *Number Theory* umbrella, or fold the reference into an already existing *Number Theory* umbrella, within the article, go ahead and do so.