Knowledge base proposal for MSE
TL;DR Is there a canonical blogging or knowledge base service attached to MSE? Also, can we use this service (if it exists) as a source for marking duplicates? If not, can we build one?
In principle, MSE is about asking questions and giving answers to them. In the last years, though, MSE has become more and more a resource for mathematical content which is useful to all people, not just those asking the question. The guidelines are very clear about duplicates. The focus has shifted away from helping an individual user to building up a big database of mathematical knowledge. In some cases, answers have even produced interesting theorems that were not known before.
However, within MSE this knowledge can always only be spread in the context of a question. This means the "trigger" of sharing the knowledge needs to be a question. And it makes this knowledge not so easy to find. Is this really the right tool to build up a knowledge database?
Some topics get asked again and again, and when trying to mark questions as duplicates I always find it a bit weird that I need to gather some random duplicates by hand without having a canonical reference that I can link to. I know that there has been a list of reoccurring duplicate topics, but this list is not maintained well enough and moreover it still stays within the paradigm of using questions as a reference. I know this is basically how MSE works but I am wondering if it is the best way.
Just to give you one example. We have probably 300 questions about the basics of tensor products, and every other day a new one is asked (well, not really new). Many resources outside of MSE will already answer these questions right away (such as the notes by Keith Conrad), but currently of course this cannot be used as a duplicate resource. It would be just so nice to have a "MSE article" called "Introduction to tensor products" which answers all the basic questions and can be extended regularly when it becomes necessary for marking duplicates.
Notice that I am not asking for a complete textbook or a complete algebra introduction, rather a list of independent high-quality focused articles that can grow over time. And they should be easy to access within MSE. This also means they should not be "buried" within the hundreds of thousands of answers already given that are not suitable as a resource.
Over time of course these articles will also be too much, but they should be votable and taggable so that the good ones are most easy to find.
Assume that I have something mathematical to write about, and I am sure many people using MSE for learning, say, category theory, will benefit from it. Also assume it's not a research article. Then currently the approach will be probably to start a blog on my own (if I haven't already), link it to my MSE profile, and link it when appropriate. So every person will have their own blog. But this approach is opposite to how MSE currently works: we are a big community on the same platform where we constantly share knowledge with each other, and separate blogs do not support this. This is also why I am wondering if we could somehow integrate this in MSE.

Maybe the community blog can be restored elsewhere

There is a feature of articles on SO, but not on other network sites.

@ParamanandSingh It seems that articles are related to collectives - FAICT they are available only on SO, too. If somebody wants to have a look, they can be found here. There is a related feature request - it was received rather negatively: Add collectives to other sites.

I think there has been some misunderstanding somewhere.  Stack Exchange has always been about building an archive of knowledge -- in the form of high-quality questions and answers.
That is not relegated to some separate blog; that is a core purpose of Stack Exchange itself.  This is not some new shift over the past few years; this has been the model for Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange from its very inception.  Many in the Math.SE community may not have been thinking of Math.SE in those terms, but that's because of a mindset among some/many Math.SE users, not because of changes in the mission and purpose of the Stack Exchange network.  This has been a long-standing tension on Math.SE, where many Math.SE users have been using or thinking about the Math.SE site in a way that is (in my opinion) frankly not 100% aligned with what Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network were designed for.  It sounds like you are rediscovering that original mission.
The canonical knowledge base service is the repository of questions on Math.SE.
I believe that what you're looking for is a "canonical Q&A". In other words, when you see dozens of posts that are all special cases of some more general question, I suggest that you post the general question, and then answer it (that's the "canonical").  Then, optionally, you can vote to close those special cases as duplicates of the canonical.
On the Stack Exchange platform, knowledge is recorded in Q&A pairs.  Not articles or blog posts.  So you do need to be able to formulate it as a well-formed question, that could stand on its own, with answers.

Isn't https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalisations-of-common-questions meant to be our "canonical Q&A"?

Thank you for sharing this perspective that MSE always had this goal of building up a knowledge database. Regarding your suggestion to post articles as questions, I don't like it for several reasons. 1) I don't have a question but I need to pretend to have one. 2) Semantically and from SEO perspective it doesn't make sense either. These will literally have a URL with "/questions" inside. 3) As mentioned it is buried in a lot of other questions. Do we at least have a tag for these kind of (non-)questions? I think we need a link on the site that makes these resources easy to find.

So to continue the example with tensor products that I mentioned, even if we had some resource that I could link to to mark a question as a duplicate (and of course also to help the OP to learn this topic properly), currently there is no easy (!) way to tell if there is such a resource. Hence my proposal.
