# What is the purpose of (learning) tag? Should it be synonym of (homework)?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have noticed that the tags [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) and [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) are between [suggested synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). Personally I don't think it's a good idea; especially because of special status [the homework tag has](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question). Therefore I've decided to bring this up at meta. This might be also an opportunity to discuss what should be actually the content of [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) tag.

The [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) does not have have a [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/learning/info) at the moment, so the intended usage can be guessed only from how it was used so far and from the name of tag. I would expect this tag to be about learning strategies, recommendations how to learn some particular subject, studying habits, and similar stuff.

**EDIT:** The synonyms seems to be already away from the [list](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms). So only the question about the content of the tag and suggesting a reasonable tag-wiki remains.

Comment: Only marginally related: I thought that I should be able to vote on this synonym suggestion, since I have sufficient reputation in (homework). It seems that I am not. So I would need to have 5 upvotes in (learning) to be able to vote?

Comment: Martin, I agree with you. I have voted against the synonym (you can do so through the [tag:homework] synonym page).

Comment: I would say every question is about learning.  You make a good guess as to what this tag might mean, but if so, it would probably be better to call it learning strategies instead of just learning.  Can we just delete the learning tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially just stealing from the OP for now.

**Proposed tag-wiki for [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)**

> Questions about the process of learning mathematics, both inside and outside a formal environment, including learning strategies, recommendations for learning particular subjects, and studying habits.

Feel more than welcome to edit and improve.

Comment: As I mentioned above, can we at least give it a better name?  Any question is about learning.  Maybe there isn't a better name.

Comment: I think of the (learning) tag as something of the opposite of (pedagogy). The latter is about how to give. The former is about how to take.

Comment: Perhaps (studying) rather than (learning)?

Comment: Studying is a method of learning, not a goal in itself.

Comment: @Arthur Since this answer has 5 upvotes, I've [suggested a tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/37705) based on it. Of course, it can be further improved (and discussed here, if needed).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with this assessment.

I voted against this synonym through the [homework] synonym page. It appears that by now someone else has also voted against it, and the suggestion was rejected.

Comment: Thanks, Asaf...

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  They are not synonyms.  Much of my mathematical "learning" has come not out of "homework" but out of just what it sounds like "learning."  Surely "learning" can take place in the context of "homework," but the restriction is arbitrary and unnecessary, and, I believe, too restrictive.