# Is it ok to ask for confirmation in some exercises?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, solution-verification

I solve some exercises but I'm self-studying and some books do not have answers to the exercises, is it ok to ask if the solution is plausible here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### YES!

Use this tag in your question:
[solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification)
But just show what have you tried, as needed in [homework](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: @Gustavo Bandeira And may I suggest: once the solutions are verified to be correct, add'em as answers and accept them, so the questions don't show up as unanswered.

Comment: @GitGud Well, actually a "Yes" can be the correct answer to "Is my solution correct?" (ironically this is the case here as well). Rewriting from "Is $x=y$? -- Noob" "Yes! -- expert" to "What is $x$? -- Noob" "$x=y$ -- Self answer by Noob" "Yes! -- expert" would be confusing. See also [Questions that ask to verify a solution to problem](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8424/questions-that-ask-to-verify-solution-to-problem/8449#8449)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Formally you're correct. However people might refrain from giving such short answers. Looks like fishing for reputation. At least I'd refrain from giving such answers, but if the community as a whole has no problems with such short answers, then it's OK.

Comment: @GitGud If you're worried about coming off as a rep fisher, you can always post a CW answer.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I'm not even sure what CW is about. Can't find anything in the FAW about it. But from little I gathered about CW, I suppose it would be against the rules to CW such a trivial answer.

Comment: *FAW $\to $FAQ.

Comment: @GitGud Strange. I couldn't find any information on this either. I have since asked [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9451/43351) to try and obtain an answer.