Why is my question being closed for not explaining "why the question is interesting or important"?

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: A right-angled triangle has sides of integer length. Its area (in square metres) is twice its perimeter (in metres). What are the lengths of the sides

For info, this is the original text:
A right-angled triangle has sides of integer length. Its area (in square metres) is twice its perimeter (in metres). What are the lengths of the sides?
The equations I have made so far is:
Using Pythagoras' Theroem and Area Formula:
ab4=a+b+a2+b2−−−−−−√
Using Heron's formula:
s(s−a)(s−b)(s−c)=4(a+b+c)2
For LHS:
(a+b+c2)(a+b+c−2a2)(a+b+c−2b2)(a+b+c−2c2)
116((a+b+c)(b+c−a)(a+c−b)(a+b−c))
116(((b+c)2−a2)(a2−(b−c)2))
Please find the original link for the question here: https://www.maths.uq.edu.au/qamt/papers/Year9-10-2022-Paper.pdf Question 4

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/14578, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/14578

The place to ask questions about why a question is closed is in the comments below that question, or in the dedicated thread for reopen requests (​​ https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34447/ ).  If every person who had a question closed were to create a new meta post, meta would quickly become useless.

I just voted to undelete the question, and as of now it is undeleted. It is a fairly interesting question!

Another place to ask might be the CURED chatroom, where your question was proposed for deletion repeatedly (first, second). Two of the deleters are owners of that room, too.

I have added reasons for re-opening the question. Is it adequate? If not, how do I improve it?

Now the question has enough support to fix the deletion and closure due to lack of context. Then would you still disagree to closure as a duplicate of A right triangle with integer sides has area equal to twice its perimeter. Find sum of all possible circumradii.?

@peterwhy, no, I disagree. I feel that, though the given information is the same, it has different possible methods to solve the question and is hence different.

The decision should be: does the proposed duplicate answer your question? New possible methods can still be posted to the proposed duplicate.

@peterwhy, I believe answers to my question more pertinently answer the question.
